# script error- ready function()?

Tags: javascript

i have two ready function() script,how to combine  this  to keep in header file..can someone rearrange code to help me,,,pllz

1)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {  

    //Get the height of the first item
    $('#mask').css({'height':$('#panel-1').height()});  

    //Calculate the total width - sum of all sub-panels width
    //Width is generated according to the width of #mask * total of sub-panels
    $('#panel').width(parseInt($('#mask').width() * $('#panel div').length));

    //Set the sub-panel width according to the #mask width (width of #mask and sub-panel must be same)
    $('#panel div').width($('#mask').width());

    //Get all the links with rel as panel
    $('a[rel=panel]').click(function () {

        //Get the height of the sub-panel
        var panelheight = $($(this).attr('href')).height();

        //Set class for the selected item
        $('a[rel=panel]').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        //Resize the height
        $('#mask').animate({'height':panelheight},{queue:false, duration:500});         

        //Scroll to the correct panel, the panel id is grabbed from the href attribute of the anchor
        $('#mask').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 800);     

        //Discard the link default behavior
        return false;
    });

 });
</script>
```

2)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
        function(){
            $('#testim').innerfade({
                animationtype: 'slide',
                speed: 750,
                timeout: 4000,
                type: 'random',
                containerheight: '102px'
            });

    });

    //Get the height of the first item
    $('#mask').css({'height':$('#panel-1').height()});  

    //Calculate the total width - sum of all sub-panels width
    //Width is generated according to the width of #mask * total of sub-panels
    $('#panel').width(parseInt($('#mask').width() * $('#panel div').length));

    //Set the sub-panel width according to the #mask width (width of #mask and sub-panel must be same)
    $('#panel div').width($('#mask').width());

    //Get all the links with rel as panel
    $('a[rel=panel]').click(function () {

        //Get the height of the sub-panel
        var panelheight = $($(this).attr('href')).height();

        //Set class for the selected item
        $('a[rel=panel]').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        //Resize the height
        $('#mask').animate({'height':panelheight},{queue:false, duration:500});         

        //Scroll to the correct panel, the panel id is grabbed from the href attribute of the anchor
        $('#mask').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 800);     

        //Discard the link default behavior
        return false;
    });

});
</script>
```

when i keep like this one progoram is running,one not,,how to fix,,,,

Comment: Please make your question clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, but if you want to know how to reduce your code to one ready block, then put the code from each ready block into it's own function (without the ready block.  Then, have one ready block that just calls those two functions.

Just make one ready block:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    Init1();
    Init2();
});

function Init1() {
    // copy code here
}

function Init2() {
    // copy code here
}
```

Then, move the existing ready blocks into functions called `Init1()` and `Init2()` (without the `$(document).ready`).  I assume you can copy paste the code into the right functions yourself as you know what goes where better than I.

Comment: yes,,,i like to call two functions in one ready block, can you plz rearrange the code...

Comment: I added an example to my answer.

Comment: am sorry ,,am not at all familiar with java script codes... i dont know to keep this,, if u arrange the code it will helpful?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(
        function(){   <<<<<<<<<<< delete
            $('#testim').innerfade({
                animationtype: 'slide',
                speed: 750,
                timeout: 4000,
                type: 'random',
                containerheight: '102px'
            });

    }); <<<<<<<<< delete
```

Make it look like this

```
$(document).ready(
    $('#testim').innerfade({
      animationtype: 'slide',
      speed: 750,
      timeout: 4000,
      type: 'random',
      containerheight: '102px'
    });
```